# Rails: Choosing an object on button click and showing info on modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a long list of cats in my database

```
Cat(id: integer, name: string, gender: integer, home: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

and on my web page I wish to open a [Bootstrap modal](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/) with the information of only one cat in it. The id of the cat would be determined on button click. In my `CatsController` I have defined

```
def index
 @cats = Cat.all
end
```

and the path `/cats/` shows

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Open Modal </button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can this be done the Rails way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a loop to iterate over cats , in the loop body include your modal and your button .

Inside your button put a :

```
data-target="#myModal_<%=cat.id%>">
```

And inside your modal put a

```
 id="myModal_<%=cat.id%>"
```

I'm afraid this is a matter of client side and rails is more server oriented .

Comment: Such a simple solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help ;)